# Ruby: DRY class methods calling Singleton instance methods

Tags: ruby, delegates, singleton

I have the a Singleton class `ExchangeRegistry` which keeps all the Exchange objects.

Instead of needing to call: 
   `ExchangeRegistry.instance.exchanges`

I want to be able to use:
`ExchangeRegistry.exchanges`

This works, but I'm not happy with the repetition:

```
require 'singleton'

# Ensure an Exchange is only created once
class ExchangeRegistry
  include Singleton

  # Class Methods  ###### Here be duplication and dragons

  def self.exchanges
    instance.exchanges
  end

  def self.get(exchange)
    instance.get(exchange)
  end

  # Instance Methods

  attr_reader :exchanges

  def initialize
    @exchanges = {} # Stores every Exchange created
  end

  def get(exchange)
    @exchanges[Exchange.to_sym exchange] ||= Exchange.create(exchange)
  end
end
```

I'm not happy with the duplication in the class methods.

I've tried using `Forwardable` and `SimpleDelegator` but can't seem to get this to DRY out. (Most examples out there are not for class methods but for instance methods)

Comment: Tom, We've found a question this is a duplicate of, so I'll mark it so.  It's no stain on your reputation...  your question remains as a valuable place for searches to land on.  Thanks for asking it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The forwardable module will do this.  Since you are forwarding class methods, you have to open up the eigenclass and define the forwarding there:

```
require 'forwardable'
require 'singleton'

class Foo

  include Singleton

  class << self
    extend Forwardable
    def_delegators :instance, :foo, :bar
  end

  def foo
    'foo'
  end

  def bar
    'bar'
  end

end

p Foo.foo    # => "foo"
p Foo.bar    # => "bar"
```

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer is clever, but seems needlessly complex (not to mention to performance penalty of `method_missing`.

The usual way to solve this is to just assign the instance to a constant.

```
class ExchangeRegistrySingleton
  include Singleton

  # ...
end

ExchangeRegistry = ExchangeRegistrySingleton.instance
```

Comment: This causes the singleton to be instantiated at load time, which may not be wanted.  Also, If a singleton can be instantiated at load time, there's little reason for it to be a singleton.

Comment: @Jordan - You may need to edit the answer now as accepted answer has changed :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of `method_missing` hook and delegate the method calls to `instance`.

```
require 'singleton'

class ExchangeRegistry
  include Singleton

  # Missing methods will be delegated to `instance` if an implementation is available.
  # Else `NoMethodError` will be raised via call to `super`
  def self.method_missing method_name, *args
    if instance.respond_to? method_name
        puts "** Defining new method: '#{method_name}'"
        (class << self; self; end).instance_eval do
            define_method(method_name) do |*args|
                instance.send(method_name, *args)
            end
        end
        instance.send(method_name, *args)
    else
        super
    end
  end

  attr_reader :exchanges

  def initialize
    @exchanges = {} # Stores every Exchange created
  end

  def get(exchange)
    @exchanges[Exchange.to_sym exchange] ||= Exchange.create(exchange)
  end
end

# By default, there is no class method - `exchanges`
p ExchangeRegistry.singleton_methods.grep(/exchanges/)
#=> []

p ExchangeRegistry.exchanges
#=> ** Defining new method: 'exchanges'
#=> {}

# After first call to `exchanges`, a new class method is now available
# Future calls will not hit `method_missing` again.
p ExchangeRegistry.singleton_methods.grep(/exchanges/)
#=> [:exchanges]
p ExchangeRegistry.exchanges
#=> {}
```

[Another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34830430/794242) of this question indicates that there is performance penalty for handling `method_missing`.  Hence, I have updated the answer to define the class method when first time a `method_missing` is reported. The update is based on article: [Dynamically create class methods in Ruby](http://ryanangilly.com/post/234897271/dynamically-adding-class-methods-in-ruby)

Comment: Why not just `SomeConstant = SingletonClass.instance`?